# How to attach a beam perpendicularly to a wall?

Tags: joinery

I am trying to figure out how to attach the three parallel wooden beams on the picture below to <s>a wall or a wooden base</s> a wooden base made of [this](https://www.k-rauta.fi/tuote/havuvaneri-tuonti-cc-15x2400x1200mm-ce2/6405422690893). The connection must be solid because it will be used for pull-ups from the smaller wooden plate's side (front side on the second picture). What would be the most secure way to perform that? I don't really care about the looks, it can be however ugly but it should be strong enough to hold a person and should not take significantly more place than on the picture.

[image: Wall mount back]

[image: Wall mount front]

[image: Wall mount]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  In order to discuss how to attach it, we must know what it is attaching to.  What materials are the wall constructed of?  Please edit your question to include this info.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. At a guess someone is going to want to ask what the wall is made from (I was just about to myself!) but really it doesn't matter given how much space you have available for fasteners and the width means you can attach to at least one stud. Screwing very deeply through the plywood into the ends of the uprights with beefy screws is probably going to be enough here, but for peace of mind you can simply add triangular support blocks underneath if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I edited the question to include the wooden base's specs. I am a little worried that the arm of the applied force is really long (~50cm), would screws and support blocks be enough?

Comment: You mention in a comment on an answer that your walls are drywall. That drywall is attached to _something_ - it's not just floating in air! What's behind it? Is it wooden studs? Is it steel studs? Is there brick or cement block or concrete lurking back there? You may need to drill a test hole or two, because this would be _very_ easy to attach if you have wood studs holding up the drywall.

Comment: Also, oddly enough, this may have been a better bet over at [diy.se] since it's not really about wood working, but about attaching things very securely to the house. (Usually I'm suggesting people there post their wood working questions here.) You may want to browse there, there have been quite a few "pull up bar" questions asked in the last few years.

Comment: Nikita, I often say this when it comes to user-designed stuff here: there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Once you're online you're not forced to design in a vacuum for so many project types, and pull-up/chin-up equipment is definitely no exception. There are loads and loads of designs out there already, wall-mounted & freestanding, DIY (of various levels) and commercial (many good alternatives for you there). I would strongly recommend just hitting up an image search and seeing the range of options. I haven't used it in a while but I bet Pinterest will have tons of related content.

Comment: @Graphus thanks! But it's actually a bit more complicated than just pull-ups, I omitted what seemed unnecessary to the project to me, it was supposed to be this on the front of the construction: https://www.oliunid.com/beastmaker-1000-climbing-hangboard.html. I tried searching a wall mount for this model but no success

Comment: @FreeMan most of my walls are drywall (including those which are put together close so that I could put a bar between them), but they seem too weak to me so I decided to build the wall mount on the image in the question and attach its back to a brick wall which is strong enough so that I wouldn't worry about whole walls going down when I try to hang in there

Comment: Most US houses are drywalled, too, but it's what's _behind_ the drywall, holding it up. There has to be something _supporting_ the drywall. Attach your bracing - whatever method you choose, to that, not the drywall itself. Yes, there are some good drywall anchors rated for 100lbs or more, but that's static weight and you're going to be doing very dynamic moving on this. You want it firmly attached.

Comment: @FreeMan, *"Yes, there are some good drywall anchors rated for 100lbs or more, but that's static weight and you're going to be doing very dynamic moving on this."* yes, and even being exceedingly conservative of the load each could take (I was previously going to use only 50lb to make a point) there are 12 just going through the hangers. That's 600lb already, being unrealistic :-) There's room for plenty more, even double that number with the design unaltered. But the design can be tweaked easily in a number of ways to spread the load, including having the floor take a large portion of it.

Comment: While a large enough collection of drywall anchors may theoretically support the weight, the force & weight will be concentrated in one fairly small location. There's not enough strength in the drywall itself to support that much weight. No individual anchor may pull out, but the whole collection may still be attached when the drywall around them gives way. Again - there has to be _something_ holding up the drywall. Attach the pull-up bar to _that_. If one hole doesn't line up with a stud, fine, use a drywall anchor, but don't rely 100% on them. But... it's not my wall.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe can use screws only to attach beams to plywood. 2 or 3 each, long and thick. But easier building and more security with exterior metal fixings such as these:

[image: truss shoe]

<sup>**Truss shoe** or **joist shoe**</sup>

Your design is complex, and uses much material. If you only seek means for pullups you can mount plates for use of pole or wood beam high in doorframe or hallway very easily:

[image: door mount pullup bar]

[image: Hallway mount]

<sup>Only side plates are permanent, pole or beam lifted out and stored elsewhere when not in use.</sup>

As you see, these options use much less material, much faster to install and no floor space taken up permanently by aparatus.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the fixing! I would really prefer to use the pullup bar design that you have suggested, but unfortunately, my apartment doesn't have indoor doors and all inner walls are drywall, so the only option for me (or the only one I could find) is to build a wall mount as in the question body and hang its wooden base on the inside of the outer wall (the only brick wall in my apartment I have access to from inside)

Comment: The joist hanger (as they're known in the US) in the first image will only work if there is horizontal blocking behind the drywall or a floor/ceiling joist. It could be used to attach to a brick/concrete wall, but one would have to use appropriate bolts through the larger holes and those really aren't (to the best of my knowledge) designed to be used. To properly use a joist hanger like that and get full strength, a 1-1/2" 16d nail is to be driven through each and every single small hole (though there are now joist hanger screws to make removal easier).

Comment: @FreeMan, you need to think outside the box with the joist hangers maaan :-) Screwed to the ply through most of the small holes and straight through to drywall through the big ones this would be plenty strong enough I bet. Hitting a stud somewhere would be good of course, but really I don't believe that's vital given the loads that drywall fixings are now capable of holding. But now we have a better idea of the requirements here I think the way forward is for the OP to redesign from scratch.

Comment: @Graphus  I strongly disagree that a joist hanger only secured to the plywood will work not because of the connection of hanger to plywood, but because of connecting the plywood to the drywall.  There must be a secure connection of the assembly to studs or masonry to transfer the loads properly.

Comment: @Ashlar, have you seen any of the tests of direct pullout resistance of decent modern drywall plugs, intended to give people hanging cabinets or shelves a realistic idea of what they can expect? Most use direct pull-out resistance (pure axial load) and acknowledge in reality a lot of it is actually sheer loading. Once you do test more accurately for that the results can be truly astonishing. There's literally no other word for it — I highly recommend taking a look. Anyway, as I say I think OP should scrap this design entirely and just copy an existing solution, or buy a commercial pull-up kit.

Comment: @Graphus The problem I see is that the applied forces are not static. The plugs are embedded in 1/2"+/- gypsum and will be subject to repeated forces of that push, pull, & twist the plugs continually stressing the adjacent gypsum matrix. Gypsum is not that strong, and the plugs will eventually loosen. Once that starts the stress from movement will increase leading to eventual failure.

Comment: @Ashlar, yes the dynamic forces are much much higher than the static load but it has now been established that drywall can withstand *far* higher loading than one would have thought. Obviously just 1-2 plugs can't be expected to take much abuse, but how about 20 of them over a large area, with compression and a healthy dose of friction thrown in for good measure? Anyway, this is interesting to speculate about but now that we have a better idea of the OP's situation (there's a brick wall available) the ability of fixings to do [this](https://imgur.com/a/bBIQ4W9) becomes essentially irrelevant.

Comment: @graphus  Good point about having many attachment points (especially at the top of the panel).  Can you give your reference for establishing drywall strength, I would like to look it over.

Comment: @Ashlar, for simple plastic plugs there's a great series of tests done by Gosforth Handyman showing pure axial resistance, while emphasising that of course under normal circumstances there's a lot of sheer stress acting at 90° to this; so even the higher-than-expected loads his tests reveal only give a hint of what you might expect in real-world applications. So, for some "Wow!" results there's one particular vid from Ultimate Handyman (he also has others) which shows the nearly unbelievable amount of weight a single shelf can support with the right fixings [here](https://youtu.be/ECDysfNhx_E)

Comment: @Graphus OK more load than I would have thought. I assume that the test shelves are using four connectors each and failures appear to max out around 150kg / 330lbs.  I assume the gypsum is mounted to studs at 40cm/16" oc. But these are static load failures.  So, I would use them for shelves, but never for an exercise bar.  I think the dynamic loads would easily exceed the failure limits especially considering that the stress on each connector will be in any direction.  The screw fittings would be especially vulnerable to weakening over time.  BTW, I have enjoyed the discussion!